# Metagenomics: Identifying most common sequences

Tags: fasta, clustering, metagenome

I am working on a project and used the following command:

```
vsearch --derep_fulllength filtered_merged.fa -sizeout -relabel Uniq -output dereplicated_filtered_merged.fa
```

and got the following output:

```
87373926 nt in 203453 seqs, min 310, max 480, avg 352
Sorting 100%
10981 unique sequences, avg cluster 2.0, median 1, max 1287
Writing output file 100%
```

The output had provided me with the data that 10981 unique sequences have been identified. But I cant seem to identify how many reads of the most common sequence were present in the input data.

Any suggestions will be kindly appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the output fasta? According to the VSEARCH docs the abundance information should be contained there (https://github.com/torognes/vsearch/releases/download/v2.15.1/vsearch_manual.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [VSEARCH docs](https://github.com/torognes/vsearch/releases/download/v2.15.1/vsearch_manual.pdf), since you have specified `--sizeout` your abundances have been written into the FASTA headers:

> --sizeout
>
> Take into account the abundance annotations present in the input fasta file (search for the pattern ’[>;]size=integer[;]’ in sequence headers). That option is active by default when rereplicating.
>
> **Add abundance annotations to the output fasta file (add the pattern ’;size=integer;’ to sequence headers).** If --sizein is specified, each unique sequence receives a new abun- dance value corresponding to its total abundance (sum of the abundances of its occur- rences). If --sizein is not specified, input abundances are set to 1, and each unique sequence receives a new abundance value corresponding to its number of occurrences in the input file.